# Trocar linhas de uma matriz

Tags: c, matriz

Abaixo está o meu código. Preciso trocar a linha 1 com a 3 e a 2 com a 4. 
O problema é que a terceira linha não está trocando e não acho o problema.

```
    int matriz[TAM][TAM], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0, aux = 0, aux2 = 0, aux3 = 0;

    printf("Informe um tamanho par para sua matriz:  \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < n; y++){

            printf("Preencha a matriz: \n");
            scanf("%d", &aux2);

            matriz[x][y]=aux2;

       }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < n; y++){
                if (x<=(n/2)){

                aux = matriz[x][y];
                matriz[x][y] = matriz[x+2][y];
                matriz[x+2][y] = aux;
                printf("%d ", matriz[x][y]);
                }

                if ( x==3 ||(x>(n/2)))
                {
                aux3 = matriz[x][y];
                matriz[x][y] = matriz[x-2][y];
                matriz[x-2][y] = aux3;
                printf("%d ", matriz[x-2][y]);
                }

        }

    printf("\n");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de `x + 2` e `x - 2` que só vai funcionar se for informado 4 para `n`, use `x + n / 2` e `x - n / 2`.

Aquilo que há de repetido dentro dos dois `if`s pode ser movido para antes ou depois deles.

Lembre que o primeiro índice é zero. Isso significa que o seu `if (x<=(n/2))`, em uma matriz de quatro linhas, irá até a terceira linha, e não até a segunda. O que você queria era usar o `<` ao invés do `<=`.

Ao invés de usar `if ( x==3 ||(x>(n/2)))`, bastava usar `else`. Além disso, devido ao item anterior, deveria ser `>=` ao invés de `>`, o que eliminaria a necessidade desse `x==3`.

No `printf` do primeiro `if`, você usa `matriz[x][y]`, mas no do segundo usa `matriz[x-2][y]`.

Você também não precisa de um monte de variáveis `aux`, apenas um é necessário.

Eis como fica o seu código com essas correções:

```
int matriz[TAM][TAM], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

printf("Informe um tamanho par para sua matriz:  \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        printf("Preencha a matriz: \n");
        scanf("%d", &matriz[x][y]);
   }
}

for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        int aux = matriz[x][y];
        if (x < n / 2) {
            matriz[x][y] = matriz[x + n / 2][y];
            matriz[x + n / 2][y] = aux;
        } else {
            matriz[x][y] = matriz[x - n / 2][y];
            matriz[x - n / 2][y] = aux;
        }
        printf("%d ", matriz[x][y]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

É possível simplificar o seu código um pouco mais e unificar o `if` e o `else` ao verificar que a posição da linha que você quer trocar (vamos chamar de `nx`) pode ser calculada a partir do `x` assim:

```
int nx = (x + n / 2) % n;
```

Para ver como isso funciona, veja que sendo `n` igual a 4, teremos que:

- Se `x` for 0, `nx` será 2.
- Se `x` for 1, `nx` será 3.
- Se `x` for 2, `nx` será 0.
- Se `x` for 3, `nx` será 1.

Isso funcionará para qualquer outro valor par de `n`.

Desta forma, o seu código fica assim:

```
int matriz[TAM][TAM], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

printf("Informe um tamanho par para sua matriz:  \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        printf("Preencha a matriz: \n");
        scanf("%d", &matriz[x][y]);
   }
}

for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        int nx = (x + n / 2) % n;
        int aux = matriz[x][y];
        matriz[x][y] = matriz[nx][y];
        matriz[nx][y] = aux;
        printf("%d ", matriz[x][y]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente. Obrigada pela grande ajuda!